# Getting error after tried publishing ASP.Net MVC web to IIS "Web deployment task failed... "

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I tried publishing my website to IIS for the second times. But today I'm getting error which is "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error: Web deployment task failed. (The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects (Version 10 or higher) is installed.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.)"

Why I'm getting this error? Before this when I tried published my website to IIS don't have issue like this. I'm stuck on this issues for 3 days now, I've tried solved this matter but still didn't work. I found similar issue like this here, I have a look and try but did not work for me.

When I try run web project on local this problem didn't appear, my web can run accordingly like usual. But only when I want to publish to IIS using web deploy getting this error.

Please help. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the error message, we need to install SMO to fix the issue.

[Installing SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver16)

If you don't know how to resolve it, and the easiest way is re-install the Microsoft SQL Server with full componments and it will take more time.

Comment: Yes, I follow your suggestion to reinstall the Sql Server and it's working. I can published again my website. Thank you!